# Simulating a screw turning a gear

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

My goal is to model the parts for a guitar in FreeCAD and Blender, and then use Blender to make sure they will work before I have them made. I've started with the tuners, which consist of a screw turning a gear (and a post attached to the gear, and a little handle and enclosure).

I've figured I need to constrain the position of both main parts, and limit their rotation. But I can't figure out the best way to rotate my parts. The game engine doesn't seem to use precise enough collision detection, and I have trouble making my screw spin with regular Blender physics. I've tried adding wind to spin the screw, adding a vortex force to the screw, tweaking the weights of the objects, and nothing really works.

[Here's](http://metaphorshear.com/files/tuner.blend) the blend file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animating gears is usually done using the [*Copy Rotation*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Transform/Copy_Rotation)  constraint, in your case you want to copy the rotation from another axis therefore you might want to use the [*Transformation*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Transform/Transformation) constraint to copy and scale the rotation from one axis to another:

[image]

[image]

Video Tutorial:
[Gear rigging tutorial constraints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1WNbpX7HPo)

Note: This is only to do an animation, I'm not sure whether Blender is suitable for simulation of mechanical parts from an engineering point of view.