# Bevel Gear Creation

Tags: modeling

I need to create a set of bevel gears for a Shay locomotive in a Sketchup project I am working on, and I was wondering if there is a Blender tutorial for this? Thanks in advance for any help you may give.

Comment: enable extra objects addon , then you can add gears through Alt+A

Comment: @Chebhou `Shift`+`A`, `Alt`+`A` plays the timeline

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8033/simulating-a-screw-turning-a-gear and http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9230/1853

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1WNbpX7HPo

Answer (score 7):

The plugin you need is called now **add_mesh_extra_objects**.
To enable it press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>. That will open the preferences window.
On the Addons tab type extra and and check the box for Add Mesh:Extra Objects

[image]

You should have new options on the add mesh menu. Select Add_Mesh_Gears_gear.

[image]

On the tool bar (<kbd>T</kbd>) You have a lot of options to create the gear you need.

[image]